# Передать localStorage из условий if else при изменениях и перезагрузке

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь менять padding у элемента при изменении его и записывать в localStorage, запись идет, но почему-то при перезагрузке все сбрасывается хотя localStorage остается.

Вот что по моему мнению показалось логичным для записи.

```
var totalDcart = document.querySelector('.dcart-total-count');
var countOfBasket = document.querySelector('.count-of-basket');

// При изменении кол-ва товаров менять padding
totalDcart.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    var padd = localStorage.getItem('padding');
    if (Number(totalDcart.innerHTML) >= 10){
        countOfBasket.style.padding = '0 5px';
        localStorage.setItem('padding', countOfBasket.style.padding);

    }else{
        countOfBasket.style.padding = '0 9px';
        localStorage.setItem('padding', countOfBasket.style.padding);
    }
});

countOfBasket.style.padding = localStorage.setItem('padding', padd);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  // var padd = localStorage.getItem('padding');
...
countOfBasket.style.padding = localStorage.getItem('padding');
```

Comment: Спасибо, только сейчас понял что не передавал значение.